# Python Discord bot error: module object is not callable

Tags: python, discord, bots

What is this error?

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import aiofiles 
import os
import requests
import json
from keep_alive import keep_alive
bot = commands.bot (command_prefix="!")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file.py", line 9, in <module>
    bot = commands.bot (command_prefix="!")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Who can help me fix this error?

What is the reason for this error? Can anyone explain this to me exactly?

Comment: Looks like commands.bot is a module and not a prefix. look at the docs for the discord library and see the proper usage

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the error message tells you that you're calling `bot` which is a module and not a class or a method, so you can try doing the following which contains of accessing the class inside the module:

```py
bot = commands.Bot (command_prefix="!") 
#or if you realize that you forgot a capital 'B' so it's like accessing the module in that way without a capital 'B'
```